# Django User "per project" group assignation

Tags: database, django, authentication, django-authentication

Here's my problem : my site has users, which can create projects, and access other user's projects.
Each project can assign different rights to users.

So, i could have Project A : user "John" is in group "manager" , and Project "B" user "John" is in group "worker".

How could I use the Django User authentication model to do that ?

From a SQL point a view, what i would like is to be able to add "project_id" in the primary key for the "auth_user_groups" table.

I don't think profile is of any help here. Any advice ?

UPDATE : "worker" and "manager" are just two examples of the permission group (or "roles") that my application defines. There will be more in the future. Eg : i will probably also have "admin", "reporting", etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need this information in the groups i think the best solution is to sub class the necessary models and make your own auth application/auth backend out of this!

I dont know if it's necessary to relate the projects to groups, you could also create an user profile that has a 1:1 relation to the user and a m:n to projects, so you could assign projects to a user and then check in your apps what projects the user is related to?

Third solution that comes to my mind would be having a model with one foreignkey to project and one to group, which might also work for you, but probably has no good usability!

The dirtiest way would probably be to add a foreignkey to group using monkey-patching (add_to_class), but i guess this only recommendable if you don't find another descent way to do it and is somehow your last resort, but not first choice!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll wait a bit to see if someone has a better solution, but i'll probably go for your first solution (subclassing)...
I don't really "need" that in group, it's only that user's rights depend on the project. Your second solution means replicating the auth_group/permission model (with tables like userprofilepermission) that Django already uses, just to add another key in the "auth_group" table's primary key... I really hope there's a descent way to extend the base auth model other than copy/pasting. 
It's really incredible that Django has such a limited auth model.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live without it in your User model and can have it an associated user profile model, how about something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from foo.models import Project

class UserProfile(models.Model):

  auth_user = models.ForeignKey('User')
  projects_where_manager   = models.ManyToManyField('Project', 
                                                     related_name="managers_for_project")
  projects_where_worker   = models.ManyToManyField('Project', 
                                                     related_name="workers_for_project")
```

Comment: Actually "worker" and "manager" are only two examples of the kind of rights my users would have. I would really like to user the "auth_group / permission" model, defining groups as data in a table instead of columns.